# Accessing the value of servlet in two jsps

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet, which sends values to a JSP1. I am setting the values in the servlet as

```
request.setAttribute();
```

and i am using

```
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and i am able to access these values in the JSP1 using expression language.

Now, I also need to use this in another JSP2.

These two JSP's are clubbed together to display in a single page. So, I need to access the values of the servlet in the second jsp as well. How can i do that?

Comment: how are you forwarding the request from jsp1 to jsp2

Comment: use session to store its value so it can be accessed on any page you want

Comment: How are the two jsp *clubbed* together ? If you are simply using inclusion (`@include` or `<jsp:include>`), no problem : they use same request and both will access the request attributes. If it is anything else (ajax, portlet, ...) pleas say what you use.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. If you are setting an attribute "attr1" in a servlet and then forwarding to a JSP (file1.jsp):

```
request.setAttribute("attr1", "first attr");
request.getRequestDispatcher("file1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And suppose in the first JSP (file1.jsp), you are including another JSP (say file2.jsp):

```
<body>
.....
<jsp:include page="file2.jsp"></jsp:include>
.....
</body>
```

Then in file2.jsp, you can access attr1 by calling the request object's getAttribute method:

```
<body>
....
${attr1}
....
</body>
```

In case of jsp:include action, when file2.jsp is included in file1.jsp, both request and response objects are passed to file2.jsp as parameters. So file2.jsp can access the attributes of file1.jsp's request object.

Comment: Please dont advise using the scriptlets _they are discouraged over the decades_. have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have both the jsp clubbed in a single page , you can simply get the attribute as,

```
   ${attributeName}
```

it refers to the object set in the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) scope . I suggest to take the tutorial for [Expression language](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-expression-language-el/)